# How do we get more Ask Ubuntu users to use meta?

Tags: discussion, users

The users page in Ask Ubuntu main page goes up to page 3988 and with about 36 users per page, that goes to about 143K users.

In meta, the users page only goes up to page 442 coming to about 16K users.

So, how can we get more main Ask Ubuntu users to come to meta?

---

**EDIT 1**
It's basically for better main site management, raising issues that affect the main site and general info concerning how to 'behave' in Ask Ubuntu - how to ask questions, how to answer, community issues, etc.

Examples of questions that require the 'attention' of a larger audience:

[What's wrong, Ask Ubuntu?: Low Voter Count](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8373/whats-wrong-ask-ubuntu-low-voter-count)
[Community Promotion Ads - 2014](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7773/community-promotion-ads-2014)
[newbie User ask and GO away forever](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8391/newbie-user-ask-and-go-away-forever)
[Unanswered questions - what to do?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8333/unanswered-questions-what-to-do)
[2014 Community Moderator Election](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8324/2014-community-moderator-election)

etc...

**Feel free to edit this question to give more info and examples**

---

**EDIT 2**
I have designed a meta.askubuntu.com ad that can be used in the main site to advertise meta. Check it below and if you like it, vote for it at http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8426/163331

Am not sure whether 'customize Ask Ubuntu' is the correct/perfect tagline there but it's changeable all the same.

I have added a grayscale and a color version of the image [in response to @Braiam](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8426/163331)

[image: Color version]
[image: Grayscale version]

Comment: In cases like this it's sensible to identify the issue and the problem before you start looking for solutions. Why do you think so few users make it into here? Is that a problem? How would the site benefit from more people being in here?

Comment: I've been on SE for like 6 years or so, and I discovered that each site have a  meta last year, I thought that meta.stackoverflow.com is the only meta for everything :)

Comment: Nice graphics, but a capital U for Ubuntu in the tag line, please.

Comment: @CarlH Already fixed that. See http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12386/163331

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only understood two days ago that the site governance is decided here at Meta (even if partially). I imagine that many users do not know about Meta, and those that know may not be conscious of its policy making role.

I think that automatic notifications to users regarding important debates or decisions taking place here would certainly help in engaging more folk.

Comment: There is a 'Community Bulletin' on the side with links to Meta questions, blog posts and *elections*. [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IO99S.png)

Comment: @minerz029 Yeah but it's bearly visible and then it just have like just 4 quesions. Then the words 'community bulletin' are not the *best* to catch the attention of someone - that's why I used 'customize Ask Ubuntu' in [my ad](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8426/163331). It's more catchy and makes you wanna know how.

Comment: Thank you minerz029, I wasn't awere of it.